# Futuristic-style cowboy drives a motorcycle and carries a water-purifying device

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie title. The film was made around late eighties/ early nineties and involves a character named Joe, I think. He is a futuristic style cowboy that drives a motorcycle. All I can remember is that he wears a stetson and long leather coat and carries a water purifying device. He also plays the harmonica. I do not know if the setting is a post nuclear war setting, but I am sure it is set in the future. Any ideas?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250139/a-post-apocalyptic-movie-with-a-protagonist-named-hunter (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [Battletruck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084887/)? The hero was called Hunter, not Joe but all of the other details seem to match.