# A post-apocalyptic movie with a protagonist named Hunter

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

This is a movie from the 1980s. I remember only fragments of it.

In a post-apocalyptic deserted Earth (Mad Max-like), a girl meets a scavenger (the good guy) called Hunter.
The girl has freckles and a snub nose, and is pretty but not particularly a beauty. I think I remember Hunter rides a motorbike.

Later, the girl is captured by the villain.  In a scene, he forces her to dance a slow together.

At the end of the movie, there is the final fight between Hunter and the villain; the girl shouts "Kill him, Hunter!". The good guy wins and <del>the two of them leave</del> leaves [riding in the sunset](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RidingIntoTheSunset).

This is most definitely a US movie, and IIRC there is no famous actor starring in it. All these actors are white. The girl is in her mid-20s, and Hunter and the villain are perhaps in their 30s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Battletruck (1982)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084887/) matches a few points. It's a post-apocalyptic setting and the main character is called Hunter who rides a motorbike.

Synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battletruck)

> Set in the aftermath of a devastating series of wars referred to as the Oil Wars, the plot is a futuristic tale of a community fighting against a local warlord in the lawless rural countrywide. A co-production between New Zealand and the United Kingdom, it was filmed on location in New Zealand and starring a number of local actors, and was part of a wave of similarly-themed films made in the wake of the success of the Mad Max series.

Mention of Hunter riding a motorbike:

> Corlie is saved from a squad of men sent to return her to the camp by Hunter, an ex-soldier armed with a high-tech motorbike

There's mention of riding off into the sunset, but it's just Hunter, no companion:

> Hunter and Corlie end up back at Clearwater, where Corlie apparently settles for good as part of the community. Ever the loner, Hunter rides off into the sunset on a horse, promising Corlie that he will be back "sometime".

Comment: It's definitely it, and it took only 10 minutes to get an answer. This is a great community. Thank you.

Comment: @Ouroboros - glad I could help!

Comment: Presumably Hunter’s bike gets destroyed in the course of the film, hence riding off on horseback?